# NSFileManager subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath does not list all directories in iOS 7 Device

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7, nsfilemanager

I am using `-subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath` API of NSFileManager to check the size of my Caches directory in sandbox. But strangely, the iOS 7 device behaves differently.

The API refuses to list all available directories and files in iOS 7 device. The response of the API seems to be fine in iOS 7 simulator though. iOS 6 SDK did not have any problem in both device as well as in simulator. I upgraded to iOS 7 SDK and now I am facing this problem in device alone.

The code which I am using to find all subdirectories and files:

```
NSArray *filesArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:folderPath
                                                                          error:&fileError];
```

I have checked that `fileError` is nil. This means that the API is succeeding its job!

However, when I print filesArray I get different responses in simulator and device. I can assure you that I have same content in the sandbox of Simulator and device, for I pull the data from same source and I will also attach a snapshot of the same below.

iOS 7 Device `filesArray`:

```
(lldb) po filesArray
<__NSArrayM 0x14571b90>(
ImageCache,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore/74738df8d1854e0ad4c6048e7fbdc308,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore/74738df8d1854e0ad4c6048e7fbdc308.headers,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/SessionStore,
Snapshots
)
```

iOS 7 Simulator `filesArray`:

```
(lldb) po filesArray
<__NSArrayM 0xc453ea0>(
com.jagli.indiansnakes,
com.jagli.indiansnakes/Cache.db,
com.jagli.indiansnakes/Cache.db-shm,
com.jagli.indiansnakes/Cache.db-wal,
com.jagli.indiansnakes/fsCachedData,
ImageCache,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore/4fd7c47ab0fe0389c6f3e93bb3b6448c,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore/4fd7c47ab0fe0389c6f3e93bb3b6448c.headers,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore/6c75ce415a2716dd675649e612e81103,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore/6c75ce415a2716dd675649e612e81103.headers,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore/74738df8d1854e0ad4c6048e7fbdc308,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore/74738df8d1854e0ad4c6048e7fbdc308.headers,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore/8c2634b44dd5d3da29c38b197b0f1fe6,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore/8c2634b44dd5d3da29c38b197b0f1fe6.headers,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore/c6e3b72117d11908215af1693754af3f,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore/c6e3b72117d11908215af1693754af3f.headers,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore/cfce42226559ef314867805e658134f1,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/PermanentStore/cfce42226559ef314867805e658134f1.headers,
RKClientRequestCache-indiansnakes.org/SessionStore,
Snapshots,
Snapshots/com.jagli.indiansnakes,
Snapshots/com.jagli.indiansnakes/Main,
Snapshots/com.jagli.indiansnakes/Main/UIApplicationAutomaticSnapshotDefault-Portrait@2x.png,
Three20,
Three20/00d1e10121911d558dbfd64141dcef0b,
Three20/0176adb95ef181f3f376e470515407be,
Three20/022bf0b8fa1b9cdaa9049f99f597f49d,
Three20/02f806ffabe3fcfe6bce321fa4e1231b,
Three20/057debd2a06f07417bc6820d1b9304ed,
Three20/05f6d269c1a7e198e8c8918b1f124c4b,
Three20/0a7ce9f21c0560e0e27cfaa483a253ff,
Three20/0da06fe3edd39fdc5dae47abaa670fb4,
Three20/100d4366e3e928cccd263fa9804a1bdd,
Three20/10fd1ebbadc630616c0c6a41d989dc2a,
Three20/127e92133360dff6a08ecfb087660477,
Three20/1280e9afcc1c334ac5e54be03ea350d5,
Three20/15d6337251920fca03af1f4ecabc6b56,
Three20/18bcc9cb4478d0786cce1b18e474e26d,
Three20/1a9433ca06250061d77556370734c8f5,
Three20/1c77b07c0a7cbfdedd603db36f1286b5,
Three20/281aa8cdbc3d85f97feca841200f47e3,
Three20/2d5d8563516160e4e34282a9b58abe5b,
Three20/301809cb0e34c1a257cc7eaa420d14ed,
Three20/36b0208702eca40fada26b6994e74b45,
Three20/3762f465b5bbdb4b25581786c4cb4c5c,
Three20/3cfdb4630bb21bb784a99e1b703b526b,
Three20/4b6608feb6394f675bb78506486dbd3a,
Three20/4db4d586a4c9d68b69d7a2e158133252,
Three20/5215c70cd2868de6a429002f4b3c16ad,
Three20/5462df992093e3ed5b72ea9f6887d6b8,
Three20/5c2827e499ab79217df994f317ca1ff2,
Three20/6626f4a32279bbcf2a70c9b3e26e27db,
Three20/663bb5de9aeb698923b5e36c8eb43c31,
Three20/710b4e130b6494bca336bcaf2c5fd99d,
Three20/7725b4d768f12c9a3f57ad831c5169eb,
Three20/7af9be05f9ccf312f1561bbd01512b42,
Three20/7cbb43776684ddc26977084938c86bfb,
Three20/841eed7ca99b96cc844a37b02b684953,
Three20/84a67429b1875ac54a6bd9a2fca7fb02,
Three20/8d118946bc8abe1752283c887ae73254,
Three20/91f1eceb43b3363d68da96da085982a3,
Three20/9340302f7f8bc8f752df3f6c96ca5a75,
Three20/98772c3b24849a69b32b08d2c40aa7f4,
Three20/98d0907a5a408cbbeb3cf17ffe2ec9ee,
Three20/9d571ffd47a3eb6d03b8b4d85efa8a33,
Three20/ad24e499780426a1c9ee025f66098bda,
Three20/ad64dc0e42343381d1704f7e4249a9a3,
Three20/b0f05b42788e22b14323a67562e40ac1,
Three20/b2be29e473aad737a769cead95c23e6a,
Three20/b505b10087b332a86d841542ae4ac021,
Three20/b5a1af2586322faec63d18b901fdbfa0,
Three20/b68c96c1ac8a3daedc61df30334cbf18,
Three20/b8b74328816016c3e67fd420703abb73,
Three20/bce04e7ab6a3ed02084c74514a1d5f66,
Three20/c19c7acadf371db6f04c27a46371e16b,
Three20/c244f53752be70826fbf806f501860f4,
Three20/c6e8061e7324b5bd7210a42076bb894d,
Three20/cc5af910d8e927a4017246ba67df7888,
Three20/d07aadf568a0f505f2120c07a84bbdd7,
Three20/d401b8ea86d5951bb126e3aaa11dd781,
Three20/d5d0f328b8554a7b79f194ac30db60c7,
Three20/d5dcb78d9d6282348654eeec382541ba,
Three20/dac14b835a7109fec8ee7d2c73547f80,
Three20/e1d7c76b7dfb7a88ef1de4273f5d3070,
Three20/e2f7ce24b5900a3b9feab9b32aff52e2,
Three20/e65980f08e3964eab5b2d77301c0f97f,
Three20/e67d6d49ea874429dc813a5170a40a60,
Three20/e803b862ed4c571c40a99fbfd75ee8a7,
Three20/e98b2403993127c469c7841d35c90e85,
Three20/eb035236d7c70f3815d3165f7b61aceb,
Three20/f14d0e40ba326c14fd4321d3f4bae5f0,
Three20/f61bc021b4ad11bb8e7718122080436a,
Three20/f710c8decda280789c522082471b1648,
Three20/f82007c3f813be291193aadb9014286d
)
```

Clearly `-subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath` is failing to fetch all the paths in device. For confirmation and to assert my point that the files are existing in the device, please see this snapshot:

[image]

For now I am disabling this feature in the app!

Comment: there is no question here and I agree it looks like a bug ... report it to apple -- not to SO

Comment: Sure I will, I just needed to be double sure about it. And if it is a bug I would have to strip off a nice feature in my app due to Apple's mistake!

Comment: Filed a bug report: 15048184 The status is 'open' but no updates from Apple yet. What does this mean?

Comment: You are not alone in having issues with NSFileManager and NSMetadataQuery with iOS 7

Comment: i've also seen 'subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath' omitting some files *sometimes*. awful API.

Answer (score 1):

The possibilities seem to be:

1. The files and directories are not on the device.
2. The files and directories are on the device but the `subpaths` API is misbehaving.
3. The files and directories will be on the device sometime after you're performing this test because they haven't been written out yet.

If you think the directories and files are there on the device, test for them:

```
  -[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:]
  -[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:]
```

Comment: I agree that 1 and 3 are possible, but the files are being successfully downloaded and shown in the application's UI before I took a snapshot from the organiser window's sandbox contents. I have taken care not to miss out especially what you meant by point 3. So I will have to file a bug report then. Thanks for your time.